# Relocation package and benefits on offer contract

Tags: job-offer, contracts, relocation, benefits

Yesterday, I received a call from a company in the UK, and they let me know that they are willing to make an offer for the software engineer position. The hiring manager asked me my desired salary and offered 5k less but included the relocation package and other benefits like (setup cost coverage etc.). I asked him when they re planning to send me the written offer. And he told me that I would receive it a few days later.

Now I'm wondering, those "Benefits" and the relocation package are usually included in the written offer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The hiring manager asked me my desired salary and offered 5k less but included the relocation package and other benefits like (setup cost coverage etc.).

That's a  negotiation trick. Base salary is way more valuable than relocation bonus. You get the salary every year and it's the reference point for you next raise. Relocation bonus is a one time payment.

> So, now I'm wondering if those "Benefits" and the relocation package will be included in the final written offer.

Yes, they should be. If they are not, call them up and ask to have them added to the offer. This is standard practice: The offer is a contract and everything that's not in the offer would be difficult to enforce if the employer pulls back.

Comment: I understood the negotiation trick, and I was waiting for a lowball offer. But the thing that I will receive at a later date is the written offer, which raised a few concerns.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

They *should* be included in the written offer - if not there's no issue with you then chasing them up, you can do so politely at first as it could easily be a genuine oversight if they don't typically do this so I wouldn't assume bad-faith unless they get shady. I definitely wouldn't be making that move without those details in writing!

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will keep them in mind before accepting anything.